# set all textfields to blank when clicking cancel button of the action sheet (iOS)

Tags: ios

i want to clear all my textfields when clicking cancelButtonTitle: on action sheet;

here is my action sheet code:

```
- (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"No Way!"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes, I’m Sure!"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you haven't implemented UIActionSheet delegate:

```
#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) {
        //Clear textfiled at here
        self.firstNameField.text = @"";
    }
    else{
       //Do somethings for @"Yes, I’m Sure!"
    }

}
```

Comment: how do i clear text fields then on if statement, and for else set up to do nothing............           i have                     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameField;

Comment: thank you so much, how about at alert...i cant seem to find the same method... want to clear textfield at button "OK"...here is the alert method...- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"New Contact Saved"
                          message:msg
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

Comment: i have got it its basically the same...#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex)

Comment: @Artan You are right for UIAlertView. If the answer helps you, you can check the hook at right side.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to simalone's answer, which states you will need to implement the following action sheet's delegate method:

```
#pragma mark - UIActionSheetDelegate
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) {
        //Clear textfileds at here
    }
    else{
       //Do somethings for @"Yes, I’m Sure!"
    }
}
```

If you wanted something a bit automatic, you could create a category on UIView, and implement the following recursive method:

```
UIView+ClearTextFields.h

-(void)clearAllTextFields;




UIView+ClearTextFields.m

-(void)clearAllTextFields
{
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        [(UITextField*)self setText:nil];
    }

    for (UIView* subview in self.subviews)
    {
        [subview clearAllTextFields];
    }
}
```

If you needed to also clear all TextViews, you could add the following to the above method:

```
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
    {
        [(UITextView*)self setText:nil];
    }
```